# How to use Microsoft graph API without Login prompt

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I have a custom application (Desktop C#) when I push a button it send messages to Microsoft Teams. the problem is whenever I run the program for the first time, I need to login into my Microsoft account.

How to send/post message  without prompt?(use Microsoft Graph API)

here's my code:

```cs
 private static string ClientId = "49414fb7-f415-4a84-bac8-XXXXX";
 private static string Tenant = "c7b6c891-cd42-41c4-8b44-XXXXX";
 public static IPublicClientApplication PublicClientApp;
 string[] _scopes = new string[] { "user.read","Group.ReadWrite.All" };

 private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PublicClientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId)
       .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, Tenant)
       .Build();

        AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
        authResult = await PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(_scopes).ExecuteAsync();
        var accounts = await PublicClientApp.GetAccountsAsync();
        var firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault();
        authResult = await PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenSilent(_scopes, firstAccount)
             .ExecuteAsync();


        if (PublicClientApp == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("NULL");
            return;
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(memoEdit1.Text.Trim()))
        {
            return;
        }


        IntegratedWindowsAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new IntegratedWindowsAuthenticationProvider(PublicClientApp, null);
        GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);


        ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage();
        chatMessage.Subject = null;
        chatMessage.Body = new ItemBody();
        chatMessage.Body.ContentType = BodyType.Text;
        chatMessage.Body.Content = memoEdit1.Text;


        await graphClient.Teams["2ae3bf3f-e84b-4996-975c-495318cXXXXX"].Channels["19%3a63cf071a84b04f9aa381133a0e6XXXXX%40thread.skype"].Messages
            .Request()
            .AddAsync(chatMessage);
        memoEdit1.Text = "";
    }
```

[image]

Note: I create this as test. as for production it need to post message every 1 hour automatically without user action

Comment: just a thought if you want to post something to teams on every 1 hour or in a specific schedule. Why cant you use flow to do this repetitive task?

Comment: @RagavanRajan it's because I need to integrate it into desktop application. where the application is attendance. so if there's no one coming to class, it will inform the teacher or authority. second reason is, I don't use flow because i can't find the trigger thats fit to use

Answer (score 2):

To achieve what I want, I hardcoded the username and password. if there's a better answer please don't hesitate to post it

```
public partial class App
{
    static App()
    {
        _clientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId)
            .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, Tenant)
            .Build();
    }        
    private static string ClientId = "XXX-XXX";
    private static string Tenant = "XXX-XXX";

    private static IPublicClientApplication _clientApp;

    public static IPublicClientApplication PublicClientApp { get { return _clientApp; } }
}


  private async void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] scopes = new string[] { "Group.ReadWrite.All" };
        UsernamePasswordProvider authProvider = new UsernamePasswordProvider(App.PublicClientApp, scopes);
        GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
        String password = "XXXXX";
        System.Security.SecureString sec_pass = new System.Security.SecureString();
        Array.ForEach(password.ToArray(), sec_pass.AppendChar);
        sec_pass.MakeReadOnly();
        User me = await graphClient.Me.Request()
                        .WithUsernamePassword("XXX@XXXX.com", sec_pass)
                        .GetAsync();

        //Testing post
        ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage();
        chatMessage.Subject = null;
        chatMessage.Body = new ItemBody();
        chatMessage.Body.ContentType = BodyType.Text;
        chatMessage.Body.Content = "Hello World";
        await graphClient.Teams["xxxx"].Channels["19%XXXXXX%40thread.skype"].Messages
            .Request()
            .AddAsync(chatMessage);            
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered using a certificate-based login (one associated with an Azure AD application)?

Comment: Hey, could you please tell which dependency contains the `UsernamePasswordProvider` class? I can't seem to find it in the default `msal4j` library for Java.

Answer (score 0):

You must login first because you are connected to grpah o behalf user. You can with graph connect like an application, you will in your code connect with the clientID and the AppSecret.
You have this information in you app on the azure ad

Comment: sorry i don't quite understand what you mean.. could you provide me some code instead ?

Answer (score 0):

[Creating new channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) message API does not support application permissions. Only options would be to either use delegated permission or a [Bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-overview). Delegate permission requires user login at least once and then you could use [Refresh token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?context=graph%2Fapi%2Fbeta&view=graph-rest-beta#5-use-the-refresh-token-to-get-a-new-access-token).

For sending proactive message using Bot, please take a look at [Proactive messaging for bots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bot-conversations/bots-conv-proactive) documentation.

Comment: is there a way for user to login without action ? (input username &password on popup) more like in the backend. thanks for informing regarding proactive. I'll try to find out

Comment: You could take a look at [Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant in Azure AD OAuth](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wushuai/2016/09/25/resource-owner-password-credentials-grant-in-azure-ad-oauth/) blog. Please take a look at [this thread](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/2657#issuecomment-392822085) before using password grant.

Comment: I already answer it. but I don't know whether it's a best answer.