# Send automated messages to Microsoft Teams using Python

Tags: python, microsoft-teams

I want to run a script of Python and in the end send the results in a text format to a couple of employees through MS Teams

Is there any already build library that would allow me to send a message in Microsoft Teams through Python code?

Comment: the steps of creating a webhook are mentioned in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65759554/3088349

Answer (score 128, accepted):

**1. Create a webhook in MS Teams**

Add an incoming webhook to a Teams channel:

1. Navigate to the channel where you want to add the webhook and select (•••) *Connectors* from the top navigation bar.
2. Search for **Incoming Webhook**, and add it.
3. Click *Configure* and provide a name for your webhook.
4. Copy the URL which appears and click "OK".

**2. Install pymsteams**

```
pip install pymsteams
```

**3. Create your python script**

```
import pymsteams
myTeamsMessage = pymsteams.connectorcard("<Microsoft Webhook URL>")
myTeamsMessage.text("this is my text")
myTeamsMessage.send()
```

More information available here:

[Add a webook to MS Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook)

[Python pymsteams library](https://pypi.org/project/pymsteams/)

Comment: Thank you. I realized i ignored the whole webhook deal because i can't find the webhook connector in my list of connectors to add on Teams..
Guess i'll have to ask the admin. Thank you :)

Comment: One important thing while creating new webhook is: 
you need to select your team's 
`Settings => Member permissions => Allow members to create, update, and remove connectors`.
If it is selected any team member can add, modify, or delete a connector.

Comment: I've got permissions to create and edit a channel, I've still been unable to find the webhook connector in the _More options_ menu, and per @Ankush, I've asked and the admin has confirmed that I should be able to create/update/remove connectors. I've tried creating a new channel and still don't get that option. I suspect I'm missing something obvious, or has Microsoft changed the API and hidden that connector?

Comment: @GerryC, I've just tried it out with Windows Teams v1.3 (64bit). Works fine. More options(...) -> Connectors -> search for "Webhook".

Comment: @mailivres, I don't even see a 'Connectors' entry on that drop-down. Difference between Windows and Linux? I can try on the lone Windows 10 box I've got. Thanks for the response!

Comment: @GerryC try it with the web version of teams. it is platform independent.

Comment: Is it possible send a formatted text like change the font or size of the font in the webhook?

Comment: @Ankush, no luck with the web version either, but on more investigation there are several steps one has to take to enable webhooks, and they're not available to be seen by guests.

Comment: @GerryC i tried and it worked for me. Yes one has to go through several steps to get this one.

Comment: @Ankush -- While I'd prefer to be able to use RESTful techniques, I'm dropping back to sending the file contents (they're text files with weather information) to the channel via email. Until I can get the Webhook located/identified, and work with that, the email will have to do. Thanks for the ideas and help!

Comment: Is it possible to send a message to the chat in this way?
As this solution is only for teams channel. For groups and chats we don't have connectors.

Comment: Do note that pymsteams is no longer maintained: https://github.com/rveachkc/pymsteams/issues/151

Answer (score 24):

## Send Msteams notification without an additional package.

A simple way to send messages to teams without using any external modules. This is basically under the hood of pymsteams module. It is more useful when you are using AWS Lambda as you don't have to add layers in Lambda or supply pymsteams module as a deployment package.

```
import urllib3
import json


class TeamsWebhookException(Exception):
    """custom exception for failed webhook call"""
    pass


class ConnectorCard:
    def __init__(self, hookurl, http_timeout=60):
        self.http = urllib3.PoolManager()
        self.payload = {}
        self.hookurl = hookurl
        self.http_timeout = http_timeout

    def text(self, mtext):
        self.payload["text"] = mtext
        return self

    def send(self):
        headers = {"Content-Type":"application/json"}
        r = self.http.request(
                'POST',
                f'{self.hookurl}',
                body=json.dumps(self.payload).encode('utf-8'),
                headers=headers, timeout=self.http_timeout)
        if r.status == 200: 
            return True
        else:
            raise TeamsWebhookException(r.reason)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    myTeamsMessage = ConnectorCard(MSTEAMS_WEBHOOK)
    myTeamsMessage.text("this is my test message to the teams channel.")
    myTeamsMessage.send()
```

reference: pymsteams

Comment: this is a solid solution, but it does in fact use an external package (`urllib3`)

Comment: Yes, but you don't have to add layers in Lambda for that module. You can just copy-paste this python code into lambda and it works ...

Comment: OP didn't say anything about deploying to Lambda?

Answer (score 17):

Here's a simple, third-party package-free solution inspired by [@nirojshrestha019's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69307189/4386191), with fewer steps and updated instructions for Microsoft's ever-changing UIs:

**1. Create a webhook in MS Teams**

Add an incoming webhook to a Teams channel:

1. Navigate to the channel where you want to add the webhook and select (•••) *Connectors* from the top navigation bar.
2. Search for **Incoming Webhook**, and add it.
3. Click *Configure* and provide a name for your webhook.
4. Copy the URL which appears and click "OK".

**2. Make a script!**

```py
import json
import sys
from urllib import request as req


class TeamsWebhookException(Exception):
    pass


WEBHOOK_URL = "https://myco.webhook.office.com/webhookb2/abc-def-ghi/IncomingWebhook/blahblah42/jkl-mno"


def post_message(message: str) -> None:
    request = req.Request(url=WEBHOOK_URL, method="POST")
    request.add_header(key="Content-Type", val="application/json")
    data = json.dumps({"text": message}).encode()
    with req.urlopen(url=request, data=data) as response:
        if response.status != 200:
            raise TeamsWebhookException(response.reason)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    post_message("hey this is my message")
```

Comment: Feels like what ChatGPT would say haha

Comment: lol well this code actually works though :-)

Comment: Simple and neat. Fellow followers, don't forget to call the function 'post_message'.

Comment: great point Alex, just added that

Answer (score 7):

Adding a code snippet based on Python's requests library for completeness.

Compared to the other answers this is useful as all major Linux distros provide a `python3-requests` package but not a `python3-msteams` package.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import requests

WEBHOOK_URL = "https://..."

def postTeamsMessage(text):
        jsonData = {
          "text": text
        }
        requests.post(WEBHOOK_URL, json=jsonData)

postTeamsMessage("Hello there")
```

Comment: Simple and elegant answer -- and most times you already have `requests` installed already