# Send ping to Python from Microsoft Teams

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, webhooks, microsoft-teams

I have an SQLAlchemy database that is having data added to it in real time. I want a way to be able to send a keyword or message in Teams and run an SQL call that will return in teams. It is the reverse of this post [Send automated messages to Microsoft Teams using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59371631/send-automated-messages-to-microsoft-teams-using-python#_=)_

Does anyone know if this is possible? Here is my current SQL call:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
link = "WEBHOOK_LINK"
myTeamsMessage = pymsteams.connectorcard(link)
pwd = "path_to_working_directory"
engine = create_engine(f'sqlite:///{pwd}\\database.db', echo=False)
pd.DataFrame(engine.execute("""
SELECT *
FROM California_table 
ORDER BY Page_Num DESC
LIMIT 1
"""))
```

Comment: Alright, a couple of things: (1) you don't have an SQLAlchemy database, that does not exist at all. (2) data to a database is always added "in real time", (3); you want an automated response to a Teams message, how is any database code relevant here?

Comment: Hopefully this is simple enough for you to understand:
* I have an SQL database
* It is streaming data
* I want an update on the last data added via a message in teams using a keyword. The SQL call will go into the message...

Comment: You could consider using a [trigger](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) or an [event](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/event.html).