# Mention channel using ms graph api

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api

I am working with ms graph and i need to integrate with ms teams. In one case i have to send a message to a channel which will contain a channel mention (@). Currently i have found how to tag a specific user using java but i cant figure out how to mention the whole channel. It is posible to do so in ms graph and if yes how?

To be more specific here is an example. Assume that i have a team named TestTeam and this team has a channel named testChannel. i need to send a message where will contain @testChannel and will send a notification to everyone in this channel.

Also in slack api i am able to do this action by using "<!channel>" in my message.

This is the code i am using in order to tag a user:

```
static void send_message(String text, String mentionName, String channelName, String teamName, String accessToken) {
  ensureGraphClient(accessToken);

  Team team = getTeam(accessToken, teamName);
  Channel channel = getChannel(accessToken, channelName, team);
  User user = getUser(accessToken, mentionName);
  if (userInChannel(user, team, channel)) {
     ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage();
     ItemBody body = new ItemBody();
     body.contentType = BodyType.HTML;
     body.content = String.format("%s.  <at id=\"1\">%s</at> ", text, mentionName);
     chatMessage.body = body;
     ChatMessageMention m = new ChatMessageMention();
     m.id = 1;
     IdentitySet st = new IdentitySet();
     Identity ide = new Identity();
     ide.id = user.id;
     ide.displayName = user.displayName;
     st.user = ide;
     m.mentioned = st;
     m.mentionText = mentionName;
     List<ChatMessageMention> cmmt = new LinkedList<>();
     cmmt.add(m);
     chatMessage.mentions = cmmt;
     graphClient.teams(team.id).channels(channel.id).messages()
           .buildRequest()
           .post(chatMessage);
  }
```

}

I also tried something similar in order to tag channels but it did not worked:

```
     body.contentType = BodyType.HTML;
     body.content = String.format("%s. <at id=\"1\">%s</at> ", text, "myChannel");
     chatMessage.body = body;
     ChatMessageMention m = new ChatMessageMention();
     m.id = 1;
     IdentitySet st = new IdentitySet();
     Identity ide = new Identity();
     ide.id = "19%xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%40thread.tacv2";
     ide.displayName = "myChannel";
     st.user = ide;
     m.mentioned = st;
     m.mentionText = "myChannel";
     List<ChatMessageMention> cmmt = new LinkedList<>();
     cmmt.add(m);
     chatMessage.mentions = cmmt;
     graphClient.teams(team.id).channels(channel.id).messages()
           .buildRequest()
           .post(chatMessage);
```

Comment: Is that channel in teams or slack or what kind of channel we are talking about

Comment: I am speaking about channel in Ms teams

Comment: You may want to give more context for your question, preferably including some code samples. That would get you better answers.

Comment: sure, let me edit my post

Comment: @Pantelisy Why don't you post of your code, what did you try up to that point, if anything?

Comment: Here's a [related thread](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/ms-teams-graph-api-cannot-mention-team-through-post-message-api/m-p/562615) talks about it.

Comment: https://ashiqf.com/2020/02/09/mention-user-channel-in-teams-using-ms-graph-api/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Introduction:

After playing around with it, here is the final result. And this is not final answer, but hope to lead for solution.

Lets start some introduction.

First lets define our post url:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/channels/19:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@thread.tacv2/messages
```

Now lets mentioning a user in graph api:

```
{
    "body": {
        "contentType": "html",
        "content": "Hello World <at id=\"0\">Maytham Fahmi</at>"
    },
    "mentions": [
        {
            "id": 0, <- the index here should be the same as in the content message
            "mentionText": "Maytham Fahmi",
            "mentioned": {
                "user": {
                    "displayName": "Maytham Fahmi",
                    "id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" <- this should be user user object id
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This is tested and working via Graph Api.

Now I come to the interested part. Sending to channel with channel mentioning looks like this:

```
{
    "body": {
        "contentType": "html",
        "content": "Hello World <at id=\"0\">General</at>"
    },
    "mentions": [
        {
            "id": 0, <- the index here should be the same as in the content message
            "mentionText": "General",
            "mentioned":  {
                        "conversation": {
                            "id": "19:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@thread.tacv2",
                            "displayName": "General",
                            "conversationIdentityType@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Teams.GraphSvc.conversationIdentityType",
                            "conversationIdentityType": "channel"
                        }
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

The results in teams, that is sent from channel mentioning
[image]

This is also working from Graph api explorer.

### The answer:

So as we can see for user mentioning we use `User` object under `IdentitySet` instance which works fine for user. I have testing it C# using Microsoft.Graph.

Here is comes the problem `Conversation` object does not exist under `IdentitySet` in C# using Microsoft.Graph. I am pretty sure this is the case for Java as well. If you have that object in Java then you should be able to make it. It is perhaps not in C#.

I have red different places, and sadly channel mentioning objects is not implemented in code yet, looks like a bug or a feature they will fix over time.

A work around solution is, you have graph api json payloads, you can make a Java client to post Jsons to the url with and your job is done.

Note: I have look at our solution, it does not support mentioning as well.

Inspiration links:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-message?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#permissions
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/chatmessagemention?view=graph-rest-1.0

Note in case you need to send notification in general, you could use [webhooks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65759554/3088349).

Comment: This works in the GUI but i need to do it through the ms graph api. I tried and the results was "This is a message @myChannel". No mention just text

Comment: It is possible to upload a code example even in C#? I tried this but does not seems to work. I updated my example to show what i am currently using

Comment: Sure, but may I ask a question. The message you want to send is it for notifications or are you developing an application. The reason I ask if you only need it for notifications there are a very simple solution that I can share with you

Comment: We need to send notifications for the progress of a task. Although the channel isn't fix, we may send messages to various channels or teams with different text and mentions

Comment: I am sorry about that but maybe you miss understand me. I know how to send a message to a channel. I needed an example of how to send a message to a channel with channel mention.

Comment: no problem, I will delete my answer and re check my code base.

Comment: Thank you a lot sir. It seems that this feature now exists only in beta version. I am not  able to +1 your answer because i have low reputation.

Comment: @Pantelisy no problem, I am really happy that this helped you. enjoy your day.