# Problem to send message to teams channel with Microsoft graph

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api

I'm working to send a message to Teams by using Graph API.

my application is a daemon application that sends a message automatically in the background.

I have written code like an official reference link below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#client-credentials-provider

in my case, I use the client-credentials-provider but, I still can't send a message, and always get the below error message.

surely I have already registered my application in Azure and set for the grant of scope

[image]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dn8i0.png]

How can I fix this?

Comment: I use this method is much easier https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57050321/how-do-i-post-a-message-to-microsoft-team-from-other-application/65759554#65759554, it does not answer your question, but might solve what you are looking for. Btw the method I use can only send to team channel not to a person

Comment: @Maytham Thank you for your answer. I have tried it and the result is ok but, that is still not what I'm looking for. this is an application for enterprises they want to use the official way to implement.

Comment: that is fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

Following this [api document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp), you need to give Application api permission `Teamwork.Migrate.All`, and try this code below:

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;

public void sendMesgAsync()
{

    var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
    var tenantId = "your_tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com";
    var clientId = "azure_ad_app_client_id";
    var clientSecret = "client_secret";
    var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
        tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
    var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

    var chatMessage = new ChatMessage
    {
        Body = new ItemBody
        {
            Content = "Hello World"
        }
    };

    await graphClient.Teams["{team-id}"].Channels["{channel-id}"].Messages
        .Request()
        .AddAsync(chatMessage);
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but, still an error like the above. @Tiny Wang

Comment: Can you try [this request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#first-case-access-token-request-with-a-shared-secret) to generate an access token, and then try [this request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request) to send message? The token should be added to request header like:`Authorization: Bearer token` there's an empty between bearer and token

Comment: try to send message via a request. if it not work, pls decode the token and check if the `roles` claim had correct vaule.

Comment: I have tried with the postman and still get `Message POST is allowed in application-only context only for import purposes. refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/import-messages/import-external-messages-to-teams for more details.` Unauthorized error. 
                        I checked the role at token and gets `"roles":["Teamwork.Migrate.All"]`, Is this why I can't send a message?

Comment: I double checked the api document, and I found this sentence. So I'm afraid we can't use client-credential-flow here for sending message to channel. `Note: Application permissions are only supported for migration. In the future, Microsoft may require you or your customers to pay additional fees based on the amount of data imported.`

Comment: I just noticed that, Do you have the other ways?. cause I can't the way to get through the above error.

Comment: since this api doesn't support client credential flow, you can only used the delegation permission, which means you can only make a user sign in first and call the api on behalf of the user.

Comment: Could you send me a link to reference?

Comment: [This section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code#web-applications) provides many samples, choose the one you need.

Comment: asp.net core call graph api, you may refer to [this one](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-1-Call-MSGraph/README.md).