# How to Find the URL to Trigger the Notification Bot C#

Tags: c#

I'm new to Notification Bots in MS Teams. So I created a sample notification bot using Visual Studio 2022 in C# and this is my reference https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n2HrdzpBg-8 and I followed the instructions in GetStarted.txt. So after uploading the .zip app package to teams, my question is where do you find the URL to trigger the HTTP notification? In debug mode we use http://localhost:5130/api/notification - what is the equivalent of this when you upload the .zip app package to teams?

Already tried searching everything in Google but can't find any answer to this.

Comment: I expect you can find the URL [in the Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/#view/HubsExtension/BrowseResource/resourceType/Microsoft.Web%2Fsites)

Comment: @stuartd do you mean I need to deploy the notification bot to Azure? Not in MS Teeams?

Comment: I have made an easier way to make notification look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65759554/3088349

Comment: @MaythamFahmi this is actually for Teams Channel, what I need is the application that you install on teams and you trigger an API to send an adaptive card to that application.

Comment: @kcbg18 I may be wrong but my understanding is that when you ‘deploy to teams’ that it’s actually deployed to Azure